# Test and developer of the psychological approach. Avoidance of tensions implement, but how?

Tags: test-management, team-management, test-planning, scrum, testing-team

Many testers are aware that sometimes it is not easy to mediate between developers and testers or to find a common approach.

Sometimes, anger also tends to rule on both sides. Within ISTQB this area is also described and some right points are mentioned.

From my experience, one should approach certain issues very carefully, build bridges and find common ground. To have an open ear for the problems, but also to recognize grievances in the processes early and to solve them.

What has always been clear over the years, however, is that the test department is only seen as an appendix to the development. How often in 20 years QA has heard the sentences "Test, oh we'll do that later", "We don't need a test for that at all". But what has also improved through the Scrum process is that the individual test is defined as part of the team, at least in this process. But tensions are also unavoidable.

I would be interested:

- How do you avoid tensions in the processes?
- How can the testers be better integrated into the processes?
- Which psychological approach should be used if the tensions between testers and developers hinder existing processes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this. the part where devs and testers are having "tension" are so year 2005... anyway to give my personal opinions

How do you avoid tensions in the processes?

> respect is the key

How can the testers be better integrated into the processes?

> Include the testers in all plannings, meetings or just anything that involves their opinions

Which psychological approach should be used if the tensions between testers and developers hinder existing processes?

> If you have existing processes, discuss to them again those processes, if they can't accept the process get their thoughts why and have them reform it and finally agree on something